# AbstractController::ActionNotFound error with routes and controller action present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Keep getting this AbstractController::ActionNotFound error even though I have the following route under the right resource:

```
post 'bulk_edit_turndown'
```

and a customized controller method:

```
def bulk_edit_turndown
```

This is my code for my button_to

```
= button_to "Turn Down", :action => "bulk_edit_turndown"
```

Any idea what is going wrong? I have tried fiddling with it for a good amount of time and simply cannot see what is wrong. Any and all help is welcome. Cheers~

Comment: what is the output from `rake routes`?

Comment: bulk_edit_turndown_leads POST         /leads/bulk_edit_turndown(.:format)                                                                     leads#bulk_edit_turndown

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your routes file.

```
resources :abstract do
  member do
    post 'bulk_edit_turndown'
  end
end
```